# Numeric pin length validation using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want user to set bitlocker pin and pin lenght should be numeric 9 digit and not in sequence like 123456789.

**Code i'm trying:-**

```
$PIN = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt 'Input your bitlocker PIN'

$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $PIN -AsPlainText -Force

Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -EncryptionMethod Aes256 -UsedSpaceOnly -Pin $SecureString -TPMandPinProtector
```

Comment: What is the maximum amount of numbers you would allow to be in a sequence? Example: 123406070 (has 4 numbers in a row). Would you want this number to be allowed?

Answer (score 2):

This code would assume that you do not want users to be able to have 3 or more sequential numbers in their pin. We can set multiple values to match against and then use regex to match the string to any value in the list.

```
$sequence = @('012','123','234','345','456','567','678','789','987','876','765','654','543','432','321','210')
$sequenceRegex = [string]::Join('|', $sequence)

Do 
{ 

    $PIN = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your PIN. Should be 9 digits and not contain a sequence of 3 or more numbers.'
}

While($PIN -match $sequenceRegex -or $PIN.Length -ne 9)

Write-Host $PIN  # just for example to confirm

$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $PIN -AsPlainText -Force

Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -EncryptionMethod Aes256 -UsedSpaceOnly -Pin $SecureString -TPMandPinProtector
```

Comment: What about in reverse in sequence though `'210','321', ...,'987'`?

Comment: What about minimum 9 digit numeric lenght for pin?

Comment: @SurajKumar updated to account for reverse sequence and check that it is 9 digits.

Comment: And what if someone enters non-digits? Or how about adding a way out if the user wants to quit?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of more rules if you like (in the code below I have added a test to rule out digits being repeated more than twice as example), but you should

- provide a means to exit if the user wants to quit
- remove all non-digits from the string the user may have entered
- provide some explanation to the user if one of the tests fail

Try

```
# create a regex sequence
# $sequence = (0..7 | ForEach-Object { ('{0}{1}{2}' -f $_, ($_ + 1), ($_ + 2)),
#                                      ('{0}{1}{2}' -f (9 - $_), (8 - $_), (7 - $_)) } |
#              Sort-Object) -join '|'

# or just define it
$sequence = '012|123|210|234|321|345|432|456|543|567|654|678|765|789|876|987'
$repeats  = '111|222|333|444|555|666|777|888|999'

while ($true) {
    $PIN = Read-Host 'Input your bitlocker PIN. Must be 9 digits. Press Q to quit'
    if ($PIN -match '^q') { $PIN = $null; break }   # exit the loop

    $PIN = $PIN -replace '\D'  # remove all non-digits from the input string
    # test length
    if ($PIN.Length -ne 9) {
        Write-Warning "You must enter 9 digits exactly.."
        continue
    }

    # test for repeated digits. Remove this block if you don't want to test on repeats
    if ($PIN -match $repeats) {
        Write-Warning "The pin may not have repeated digits more than twice (like 111 or 888).."
        continue
    }

    # test for sequences
    if ($PIN -notmatch $sequence) { break }  # corect pin, exit the loop

    Write-Warning "The pin may not have sequential digits (like 123 or 876).."
}

if ($PIN) {
    $SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $PIN -AsPlainText -Force
    Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -EncryptionMethod Aes256 -UsedSpaceOnly -Pin $SecureString -TPMandPinProtector
}
```